# How can I return the contents of a collection inside a class using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following classes:

```
public partial class Application
{
    public Application()
    {
        this.TestAccounts = new List<TestAccount>();
    }
    public int ApplicationId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TestAccount> TestAccounts { get; set; }
}
public partial class TestAccount
{
    public TestAccount()
    {
        this.Subjects = new List<Subject>();
    }
    public int TestAccountId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ApplicationId { get; set; }
}
```

In my code I have the following which returns `IQueryable<Application>` with one record.

```
var applications = DbSet.Where(a => a.ApplicationId == applicationId)
```

How can I change this so that it returns: `ICollection<TestAccount>`

Comment: Have you tried DbSet.Where(a => a.ApplicationId == applicationId).TestAccounts (i.e. your property) to get the ICollection back?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you receive a sequence of `Application` and you want to receive a sequence of `TestAccount`, which can be found at `TestAccounts` property in  `Application`, you should flattern your sequence using `SelectMany` LINQ method. Try to use next code snippet:

```
DbSet.Where(a => a.ApplicationId == applicationId)
     .SelectMany(app => app.TestAccounts)
     .ToList();
```

It will return a list of all `TestAccounts`, that was gathered inside your
`IQueryable<Application>`.

`ToList` will bring data into memory and will make it assignable to `ICollection<T>` interface (`List<T>` implements `ICollection<T>`)